# Relação entre 3 tabelas mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Estou a tentar fazer uma relação entre três tabelas. Tenho a tabela `tbl_eventos` que vai ser uma tabela onde vai guardar o evento e a respectiva data. A tabela `tbl_servicos_extra` vai guardar serviços extras que podem ser adicionados ao evento. E finalmente a tabela `tbl_servicos_extra_eventos`, esta tabela vai fazer a relação entre os eventos e os serviços extra (relação muitos para muitos).

O que acontece agora, é que ao associar um serviço extra ao evento, tenho que ir buscar todos os serviços extra que não estão a ser utilizados naquele dia do evento. Ou seja, tenho a data do evento, então tenho que fazer uma consulta para uma `<select>` que tenha todos os serviços extras que podem ser adicionados mas não podem ser serviços extras que já estão a ser utilizados no mesmo dia.

```
-tbl_eventos-
id_evento
data

-tbl_servicos_extra-
id_servico_extra
designacao

-tbl_servicos_extra_eventos-
id
id_evento
id_servico_extra
```

Estou a usar mysql e php. Para apresentar os resultados tenho o seguinte:

```
        <select name="id_servico_extra">
        <?php
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_servicos_extra");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
        ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id_servico_extra'];?>"><?php echo $row['designacao'];?></option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </select>
```

Aqui falta a filtragem para não aparecer os serviços extra que estão a ser utilizados no mesmo dia por outro evento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
  from tbl_servicos_extra se
 where not exists (select 1
                     from tbl_servicos_extra_eventos see
                     join tbl_eventos ev
                       on ev.id_evento = see.id_evento
                    where see.id_servico_extra = se.id_servico_extra
                      and ev.data = :param_data)
```

Onde tem o **:param_data** você substitui pela data que você deseja filtrar.

Comment: Era isto mesmo. muito obrigado!